# Qt, multithreading context switching with QRadioButtons

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Hi guys so I'm try switch between different threads with the way I have now by having users switch back and forth between multiple radio buttons (here I have only shown 2), when they switch the program freezes. I want to essentially create a thread, stop it then create another thread when I'm doing radio button switching. How do I accomplish this?

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);

    s1_thread = new skype_thread(this);
    connect(s1_thread, SIGNAL(skype_sig(int)), this, SLOT(skype_change(int)));
    x1_thread = new xlite_thread(this);
    connect(x1_thread, SIGNAL(xlite_sig(int)), this, SLOT(xlite_change(int)));

}

void MainWindow::on_radioButton_3_toggled(bool checked) //Skype Application is checked
{
    x1_thread->stop=true;
    s1_thread->start();
}

void MainWindow::on_radioButton_toggled(bool checked) //X-Lite Application is checked
{
    s1_thread->stop=true;
    x1_thread->start();
}
```

skype_thread.cpp:

```
void skype_thread::run()
{
    int err;

    int skype_signal=0;

    //Add programs you would like to use telephony hid here.
    wchar_t skype[6] = L"Skype";

    unsigned char data_usb[2];
    int transfer_size = 4;

    //Keyboard input event
    INPUT ip;

    //Device Handle
    libusb_device_handle* dev;

    //Initialize libusb with default device
    libusb_init(NULL);

    //Check whether the Red Button is meant to be a Hangup or Reject Button.
    bool check_d = 0;

    //Open Device VID = 0x04B4, PID = 0xE002 with the default libusb context
    dev = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, VID, PID);

    //Claim interface 3 on the device
    err = libusb_claim_interface(dev, 3);

    //Get first window on desktop
    HWND firstwindow = FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    HWND window = firstwindow;
    wchar_t windowtext[MAX_PATH]; //search term

    //We need to get the console title in case we
    //accidentally match the search word with it
    //instead of the intended target window.
    wchar_t consoletitle[MAX_PATH];
    GetConsoleTitle(consoletitle, MAX_PATH);

    //Error message for when window isn't found.
    QString error_msg = NULL;

    while(true){
        //Check window title for a match
        GetWindowText(window, windowtext, MAX_PATH);
        if (wcsstr(windowtext, skype)!=NULL && wcscmp(windowtext, consoletitle)!=0) break; //search for program
           window = FindWindowEx(NULL, window, NULL, NULL); //Get next window
    }
    while(true){
        QMutex mutex;
        mutex.lock();
        //Differentiate the different button presses.
        //Interrupt IN transfer
        err = libusb_interrupt_transfer(dev, LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN | EP_IN, data_usb, sizeof(data_usb), &transfer_size, 1000);
          if(transfer_size > 0){
              if(data_usb[0]==0x02 && data_usb[1]==0x04){ //Pickup Button Payload
              printf("Window found: %ls\n", windowtext);
              //Press the "Alt" key
              ip.ki.wVk = 0x12; // virtual-key code for the "Alt" key
              ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
              SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
              //Release the "Alt" key
              ip.ki.wVk = 0x12;
              ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
              SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
              //Bring specified window into focus
              SetForegroundWindow(window);

              //Press the "Alt" key
              ip.ki.wVk = 0x12; // virtual-key code for the "alt" key
              ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
              SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
              //Press the "Pageup" key
              ip.ki.wVk = 0x21; // virtual-key code for the "pageup" key
              ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
              SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
              //Release the "Pageup" key
              ip.ki.wVk = 0x21;
              ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
              SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
              //Release the "Alt" key
              ip.ki.wVk = 0x12;
              ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
              SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

              check_d = 1;
           }
           if(data_usb[0]==0x02 && data_usb[1]==0x01 && check_d==1){ //Disconnect Button Payload
               //Press the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12; // virtual-key code for the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Bring specified window into focus
               SetForegroundWindow(window);

               //Press the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12; // virtual-key code for the "alt" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Press the "Pagedown" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x22; // virtual-key code for the "pageup" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Pagedown" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x22;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

               check_d = 0;

           }//end if

           if(data_usb[0]==0x02 && data_usb[1]==0x01 && check_d==0){ //Reject Button Payload
               //Press the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12; // virtual-key code for the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Bring specified window into focus
               SetForegroundWindow(window);

               //Press the "Ctrl"Key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x11; // virtual-key code for the "alt" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Press the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12; // virtual-key code for the "alt" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Press the "Pagedown" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x22; // virtual-key code for the "pageup" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Pagedown" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x22;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Ctrl" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x11;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

               check_d = 0;

           }//end if

       }//end if
       if(this->stop) break;
       mutex.unlock();
       emit skype_sig(skype_signal);
       skype_signal++;
   } //end while
}
```

xlite_thread.cpp

```
void xlite_thread::run()
{
    int xlite_signal=0;
    int err;

    //Add programs you would like to use telephony hid here.
    wchar_t xlite[7] = L"X-Lite";

    unsigned char data_usb[2];
    int transfer_size = 4;

    //Keyboard input event
    INPUT ip;

    //Device Handle
    libusb_device_handle* dev;

    //Initialize libusb with default device
    libusb_init(NULL);

    //Check whether the Red Button is meant to be a Hangup or Reject Button.
    bool check_d = 0;

    //Open Device VID = 0x04B4, PID = 0xE002 with the default libusb context
    dev = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, VID, PID);

    //Claim interface 3 on the device
    err = libusb_claim_interface(dev, 3);

    //Get first window on desktop
    HWND firstwindow = FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    HWND window = firstwindow;
    wchar_t windowtext[MAX_PATH]; //search term

    //We need to get the console title in case we
    //accidentally match the search word with it
    //instead of the intended target window.
    wchar_t consoletitle[MAX_PATH];
    GetConsoleTitle(consoletitle, MAX_PATH);

   //Error message for when window isn't found.
    QString error_msg = NULL;

    while(true){
        //Check window title for a match
        GetWindowText(window, windowtext, MAX_PATH);
        if (wcsstr(windowtext, xlite)!=NULL && wcscmp(windowtext, consoletitle)!=0) break; //search for program
            window = FindWindowEx(NULL, window, NULL, NULL); //Get next window
    }
    while(true){
        QMutex mutex;
        mutex.lock();
        //Differentiate the different button presses.
        //Interrupt IN transfer
        err = libusb_interrupt_transfer(dev, LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN | EP_IN, data_usb, sizeof(data_usb), &transfer_size, 1000);
        if(transfer_size > 0){
           if(data_usb[0]==0x02 && data_usb[1]==0x04){ //Pickup Button Payload
               printf("Window found: %ls\n", windowtext);
               //Press the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12; // virtual-key code for the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Bring specified window into focus
               SetForegroundWindow(window);

               //Press the "Ctrl" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0xA2; // virtual-key code for the "alt" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Press the "N" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x4E; // virtual-key code for the "pageup" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "N" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x4E;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Ctrl" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0xA2;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

               check_d = 1;
           }
           if(data_usb[0]==0x02 && data_usb[1]==0x01 && check_d==1){ //Disconnect Button Payload
               //Press the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12; // virtual-key code for the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Bring specified window into focus
               SetForegroundWindow(window);

               //Press the "Ctrl" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0xA2; // virtual-key code for the "alt" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Press the "E" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x45; // virtual-key code for the "pageup" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "E" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x45;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Ctrl" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0xA2;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

               check_d = 0;

           }//end if

           if(data_usb[0]==0x02 && data_usb[1]==0x01 && check_d==0){ //Reject Button Payload

               //Press the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12; // virtual-key code for the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Alt" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x12;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Bring specified window into focus
               SetForegroundWindow(window);

               //Press the "Ctrl" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0xA2; // virtual-key code for the "alt" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Press the "D" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x44; // virtual-key code for the "pageup" key
               ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "D" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0x44;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
               //Release the "Ctrl" key
               ip.ki.wVk = 0xA2;
               ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
               SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

               check_d = 0;

           }//end if

       }//end if
       if(this->stop) break;
       mutex.unlock();
       emit xlite_sig(xlite_signal);
       xlite_signal++;
   } //end while
}
```

Comment: your skype_thread is missing it's stop code

Comment: also check if functions like libusb_interrupt_transfer() do return. you can check this by printing some debug output.

Comment: Yea I forgot to add in my stop code for the skype thread, but it's still doing the same thing. Libusb is not having issues as I have worked with it before and it has not giving me any issues. I can sense button presses via USB data line

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a Object and a timer to repeatedly call a slot in the object (that is moved to a worker thread)

for example:

```
class SkypeObject: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

slots:
    void start();

    void loop();

    void stop();
signals:
    //...
}
```

Then you trigger the `start` and `stop` slots after you move it to the background thread. Inside the loop slot you put the body of the while and trigger it by QTimer (or using startTimer and inherit `timerEvent(QTimerEvent)`)

Also the mutex in the while loop doesn't actually do anything to protect against race conditions except leak when you exit the while when stop is true.